# In what directions do you need to go to experience a certain rate of change of temperature?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> The temperature of a region of space is given by $T(x,y,z)=e^{-2x}(1+2y)\left(\dfrac{1}{1+3z}\right)$. If you start at the origin and fly at a speed of $2$ m/sec, what directions could you fly in initially to experience rate of change of temp of $8$ degrees per second?

My thought is to set the derivative equal to $8$, but I don't know how to find the actual angle.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the vector $v=(a,b,c)$ that gives you the direction of movement at the origin. Since the speed is $2m/sec$ it is $|v|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=2,$ or, equivalently,  $|v|^2=a^2+b^2+c^2=4.$ Now, since the change of temperature is $8$ degrees per second, you have $(\nabla T)(0,0,0)\cdot v=8,$ that is, $(-2,2,-3)\cdot (a,b,c)=8.$

So, you have to solve the system

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{r}-2a+2b-3c=8 \\ a^2+b^2+c^2=4\end{array}\right.$$

There are infinitely many solutions because the solutions of the system are the points which are in the intersection of a plane and a sphere, which is a circumference.

Comment: So I make triangles with the solutions I get to find the angle at which it is from the origin?